# Как сделать выход из цикла

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Есть код

```py
import time
import vk_api
import requests
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api import VkUpload
from random import randint

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="***")
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 183456227)
vk = vk_session.get_api()

session = requests.Session()

attachments = []
upload = VkUpload(vk_session)
image_url = '*'
image = session.get(image_url, stream=True)
photo = upload.photo_messages(photos=image.raw)[0]
attachments.append(
    'photo{}_{}'.format(photo['owner_id'], photo['id']))

print("*")

# Основной цикл
while True:
    try:
        # Прослушивание longpoll
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.raw['object']['text'] == '*' and event.from_chat:
                #цикл сообщений
                while True:
                    vk.messages.send(chat_id=event.chat_id, attachment=','.join(attachments), message='***', random_id=randint(1, 123213123))
                    print('Сообщение отправленно!')
                    time.sleep(0.2)             
    except vk_api.exceptions.ApiError:
        print('*')
        continue
    except vk_api.exceptions.Captcha:
        print('*')
        continue
```

Как сделать выход из цикла сообщений по команде, которая должна прийти из longpool?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете ввиду команду, которая придёт в сообщение то же, то просто проверяйте event.text (то есть текст пришедшего сообщение на вашу команду) и, если совпадёт, вызывайте break.

Например

```
...
if event.text.lower() == 'команда для выхода':
    break
...
```

Я бы советовал такую команду писать как большой набор произвольных символов, который будет у вас где-то записан, иначе есть вероятность, что кто-нибудь, кто напишет вам сообщение случайно угадает и закончит ваш цикл без вас)

Comment: Нужно изнутри цикла делать проверку. Для этого нужен ответ от longpoll который не будет работать т.к. цикл while с отправкой сообщений бесконечный. Если просто поставить проверку, то это ни к чему не проведёт. Так как ответ от longpoll в event уже записан, а для перезаписи нужно либо выйти из цикла, либо реализовать longpool внутри него, но вылезает новая проблема. При реализации longpoll внутри этого цикла приводит к тому, что цикл не может идти дальше так, как ждёт ответа от longpoll а при получении снова его ждёт, т.к. цикл for в этом случае бесконечен.